# Parsing a HTML with Hpple

Tags: cocoa-touch, xpath, html-parsing, hpple

I'm using Hpple to pass a HTML file. The HTML file is very similar to the following.

```
    <div class="entry">
        <p>some text here
        <a>Inside a</a>
         another text here
        </p>
       <div class="caption">
        caption here
       </div>
        <p>Blah
        </p>
    </div>
```

The result I want to see is "Some text here another text here Blah" (which ignores everything is the caption div and includes things inside  and after )

Here are some of the queries i've tried:

1. `"//div[@class='entry']/p"`
   Result: `"some text here"`
2. `"//div[@class='entry']//p"`
   Result: `"some text here caption here Blah"`
3. `"//div[@class='entry']/p//text()"`
   Result: `Nothing`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have answered this yourself, but I just had a similar problem.  To get the text I used

//div[@class='entry']//a[@inside]//*

This got me the text that was inside what you are calling Inside.  Let me know if this works.  I myself am still learning to parse HTML.  Good luck.

Comment: actually, i found out the problem. The code is actually correct, I use "//div[@class='entry']/p". But I just couldn't extract the right content from the TFHppleElemnt.

Comment: @RalfCheung, do you mind if I ask what it was you did?  I am still having some issues myself.  Thanks.

Comment: -(NSString*) getStringForTFHppleElement:(TFHppleElement *)element {   
    NSMutableString *result = ...;
    for (TFHppleElement *child in [element children])
      [result appendString:[self getStringForTFHppleElement:child]];
    if ([element.tagName isEqualToString:@"text"])
        [result appendString:element.content];
    return result;
}
in some other methods:
    tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) content = [content stringByAppendingString:[self getStringForTFHppleElement: element]];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//div[@class='entry']//p//text() - should return "Some text here another text here Blah" 
//div[@class='entry']//text() - should return "Some text here another text here caption here Blah"
```